# Grab the width and height of a device

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am using this code:

```
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
```

But it gives this error:

```
- Property "frame" not found on object of type [myViewController]
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I should modify my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you have too few arguments for the `CGRectMake` function.  You need to define your origin.  Also, you need to have `self.view` instead of just `self`.  Looks something like this:

```
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 6):

the view frame of the view from within the code is being executed

```
  CGRect myViewFrame = self.view.frame;
```

or the frame of the screen if that's what you want (says device in the title of the question)

```
CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

or this which will return the same minus status bar if visible

```
CGRect actualyScreenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.heigh);
```

And if you want to know the device screen size, then you should use:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds
```